# Unify size of QStackedWidgets

Tags: layout, qt-designer, qstackedwidget

I'm struggling with the QT Designer. Right now I'm working at a project with a QStackedWidget. Unfortunately, all the pages have a different size and are therefore a little chaotic.

Since I already put a layout behind all the widgets it is not possible to simply resize the widgets.
Do I need to break off the layout or is there a more convenient way to solve this problem?
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve.